# How to calculate the sum of bytes in a column?

Tags: table

I have this table below, how can I calculate the sum of bytes for records in Nov only? for example below I want to find rows in Nov then sum the numbers in column4 relevant to Nov only? how I can do it?

```
1 arnold   user   1933 Nov  7 13:05 
2 megan   user  10809 Nov  7 13:03 
3 sam   user    983 Apr 13 12:14 
4 mark   user  31869 Jun 15 12:20 
5 sandy   user  22414 Nov  7 13:03 
6 semon   user  37455 Nov  7 13:03 
7 andre   user  27511 Dec  9 13:07 
8 jim   user   7989 Nov  7 13:03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `awk` as follows:

```
awk '$5 == "Nov" { sum += $4 }END { print sum }'  file
80600
```

$5 represent the column relevant to months. `$5 == "Nov"` will filter the table for all records in November, then `awk` will sum the numbers in column $4

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {sum = 0}
$5 == "Nov" {sum += $4}
END {print sum}' < data
```

where `data` is your file containing the record.

Answer (score 0):

To enable you to change the target month simply, try summing all months in an array, and print the relevant array element only:

```
awk '{SUM[$5] += $4} END {print SUM["Nov"]}' file
80600
```